# How to make Agora RTM work for C# web app?

Tags: c#, agora.io, agora-web-sdk-ng

I made a web application using the C# programming language on Visual Studios 2017 and integrated the Agora RTM Web SDK but it is not working. The user interface is there, the button works when clicked on but there is no response when I click login, logout, join, leave, e.t.c. Could anyone please help me with this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Servers now require TLS version 1.2 or 1.3.  So you should be using version 1.4.0 or newer that supports TLS.  See : https://docs.agora.io/en/Real-time-Messaging/release_cpp_windows_rtm?platform=Windows&force_isolation=true

Comment: Can you add some code snippets to better explain your problem? Like how you're calling the JS functions to initialise RTM.